# chart.apis.google return 502 after Google Image Charts turned off on 14 march 2019

Tags: two-factor-authentication

I was using Google 2-FA and generate QR code using `chart.apis.google`. In another project i used `TwoFactorAuthenticator`,downloaded through NuGet Package Manager in  visual studio which actually does the same thingenter code here. Now both of them does not work due google shutdown the API on march 14 2019. Is there any alternative to generate QR code which can be scanned by google Authenticater.

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org, for many of the other charts.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsbarcode

Answer (score 0):

QuickChart (https://quickchart.io/) is an open-source chart and QR image generation service that was built to replace the Google Image Charts API.

You can use the free hosted service or use the source code here to host your own instance: https://github.com/typpo/quickchart.  Under the hood, it uses the npm [qrcode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode) package.

Generate a QR code using the `/qr` endpoint.

For example: https://quickchart.io/qr?text=Hello%20world

[image]